# How To: Control character count p tag with contenteditable="true"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

## Question:

How to control character count inside a p tag with the new html5 attribute, contenteditable="true" ?

I've found out how to do this with a textarea:
http://jsfiddle.net/timur/47a7A/ *(working)*


But how would would I do this with a p tag?
http://jsfiddle.net/47a7A/133/ *(not working)*

**HTML**

```
<p id="textarea" maxlength="99" contenteditable="true">This content is editable with a max character count of 99.</p>
<div id="textarea_feedback"></div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var text_max = 99;
    $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_max + ' characters remaining');

    $('#textarea').keyup(function() {
        var text_length = $('#textarea').val().length;
        var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;

        $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_remaining + ' characters remaining');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<p>` elements don't have values. That's for `input`, `textarea`, etc.

You want to use `text()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var text_max = 99;
    $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_max + ' characters remaining');

    $('#textarea').keyup(function() {
        var text_length = $('#textarea').text().length;
        var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;

        $('#textarea_feedback').html(text_remaining + ' characters remaining');
    });
});
```

Working example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/Hfymr

Comment: Thanks @Paul Roub! One question, I noticed that the text inside the "textarea_feedback" doesn't know its true character count until the user begins to type inside the p tag.. how would you set it up to autmoatically know (in the case the p tag has text in it already)?

Comment: I also noticed that it doesn't know when to stop either! it will actually go beyond character count and start adding -negative- numbers

Comment: I updated the example link to count at startup; it also truncates the text if we go over the max length. However, the cursor will then move to the beginning of the text in some browsers. I'll leave it to someone else to work around that (perhaps you could ask it as a separate question).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with @PaulRoub answer is that the caret cursor move to the beginning of the text if it exceeds the limit of characters. I solved this problem using [jquery caret](http://plugins.jquery.com/caret/) plugin. The following code illustrates the limit of 4000 chars for div element with `id ="#text_area"`

```
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.caret.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var limit = 4000;
        var $chars_left = limit - $('#text_area').text().length;

        $('#char_limit').text($chars_left); //char_limit is span element that is used as a counter
        $('#text_area').on('input', function (e)
        {

            var $char = $('#text_area').text().length;
            $chars_left = limit - $char;
            $('#char_limit').text($chars_left);
            if ($char > 4000)
            {
                var $text = $('#text_area').text().substr(0, 3999);
                $('#char_limit').text(0);
                $('#text_area').html($text);
                $('#text_area').caret(3999); //here is jquery.caret plugin that remain the position of the cursor
            }
        })
</script>
```